# How to fix warning MIME type text/html

Tags: javascript, html

How to fix Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html. What can cause it and how to fix ?

Comment: What "Resource"? What do you mean?

Comment: Depends on the context. How are you using the resource?

Comment: don't know, it's summercard template

Comment: If u mean the jscript load <meta http-equiv="content-script-type" content="text/javascript" />

Answer (score -2):

I assume you're looking at the Chrome console. The message means that you're loading a .js file, but the server is saying that the file is a HTML file.

You could configure the server to send JavaScript files as text/javascript, but you can also safely ignore the message. I'm pretty sure any browser will accept the script even as text/html.

Comment: I need it gone, how to do it you say ?